# Start indexing from 0 for lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to start the indexing from 1 not 0 for list so that it helps for further coding. Is there anyway to do that? 
I see many posts to do the same for data frames but not for lists.

Comment: And why do you think starting at `1` *helps* further coding?

Comment: Well, you could simply ignore index 0 of your lists, or you could use a dict indexed by integers starting at one, or you could simply *use the language the way it was designed*.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `list` and override the methods that involve indices:

```
class List(list):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return super().__getitem__(i - 1 if isinstance(i, int) else slice(i.start and i.start - 1, i.stop and i.stop - 1, i.step))
    def insert(self, i, x):
        super().insert(i - 1, x)
    def pop(self, i=0):
        return super().pop(i - 1)
    def index(self, x, start=1, end=0):
        return super().index(x, start - 1, end - 1) + 1
```

so that:

```
a = List((5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1))
print(a[1])
print(a[0])
print(a[2:])
print(a[:3])
print(a[2:5:2])
a.insert(2, 4)
print(a)
print(a.pop(2))
print(a)
print(a.index(3, 2))
```

would output:

```
5
1
[3, 6, 2, 7, 1]
[5, 3]
[3, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1]
4
[5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1]
2
```

Note that with index `1` now denoting the first item, index `0` would now take the place of index `-1` to denote the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First, get used to the index 0.

But to answer your question, you can inherit the `List` class and overwrite each method to start at 0 if you want full support... Not wise though.